# Always preprocess a specific Javascript file with Rail 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, mustache

Is there a way to always run the ERB preprocessor on a Javascript file?

I'm using Mustache to use the same templates on the client and server. I'd like to include these templates in my application.js files so they're available on the client. So I'm preprocessing my Javascript file (templates.js.erb, which then gets required in application.js) with erb:

```
App.templates.productShow = <%= MustacheController.read("product/show").to_json %>;
```

This works great but when I edit the "product/show.html.mustache" template I need to also edit "templates.js.erb" so Rails knows to recompile this file which then picks up the latest changes from the mustache template.

There's no issue running this in production since the assets get compiled when I deploy, but it's annoying when developing. Ideally I could set the preprocessor to run on "templates.js.erb" every time I reload. My current solution is to inline the Javascript in the application layout but it would be nice to keep it separate.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a guardfile for this that adds a timestamp to the end of the file. Just touching the file is enough for sprockets to recompile but if you're using git you need to actually alter the file. Otherwise anyone else who pulls in the code won't get the latest preprocessed files. Here's the code...

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

guard 'mustache' do
  watch(%r{app/templates/.+\.mustache})
end


require 'guard/guard'

module ::Guard
  class Mustache < ::Guard::Guard

    def run_on_change(paths)

      # file to be updated when any mustache template is updated
      file_name = "./app/assets/javascripts/templates.js.erb"

      # get array of lines in file
      lines = File.readlines(file_name)

      # if last line is a comment delete
      lines.delete_at(-1) if lines[-1].match /\/\//

      # add timestamp
      lines << "// #{Time.now}"

      # rewrite file
      File.open(file_name, "w") do |f|
        lines.each{|line| f.puts(line)}
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common complaint with the pipeline - that you have to touch a file that references variables for those changes to be reflected in development mode. A few people have asked similar questions, and I do not think there is a way around it.

Forcing Sprockets to recompile for every single request is not really a viable solution because it takes so long to do the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set up guard to watch your mustache directory and recompile templates.js.erb when you make changes to it. Similar to how [guard-bundler](https://github.com/guard/guard-bundler) watches your Gemfile and rebundles on change.